# PaperJs события мыши

Tags: javascript

Решил начать с азов paper. Но уже на туториале возникли сложности. 
Скрипт не реагирует на события мыши.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     
    // Create a new path once, when the script is executed:
    var myPath = new Path();
    myPath.strokeColor = 'black';

    // This function is called whenever the user
    // clicks the mouse in the view:
    function onMouseDown(event) {
     // Add a segment to the path at the position of the mouse:
     myPath.add(event.point);
    }

    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/map.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/paper-full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src="script/map.js" canvas="Canvas_Map"></script>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='Canvas_Map_Wrapper' >
    <canvas id="Canvas_Map" resize ></canvas>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите вопрос к читаемому виду. У вас два раза один и тот же код.

Comment: Приведен к читаемому виду.

Answer (score 0):

Если все делать по [документации](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/), то все и будет работать.

А именно, не оборачивать код обработчиков событий в анонимные функции.

```css
#Canvas_Map {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.js"></script>

<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="Canvas_Map">
 // Create a new path once, when the script is executed: 
  var myPath = new Path();
  myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
  // This function is called whenever the user 
  // clicks the mouse in the view: 
  function onMouseDown(event) {
    // Add a segment to the path atthe position of the mouse: 
    console.log(event)
    myPath.add(event.point);
  }
</script>

<div id='Canvas_Map_Wrapper'>
  <canvas id="Canvas_Map" resize></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вынес часть кода paper за пределы анонимной функции готовности документа ($(document).ready(function()) . Но почему же так происходит?

Comment: @СергейТимофеев так происходит, потому что papreJS ищет функции обработчиков в "корне" скрипта, при его парсинге. А поскольку вы перенесли его в анонимную функцию, то конечно, он их не находит. Спасибо принимается в виде принятого ответа)